# Flutter video player Android TV

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a video player with controls for Android TV with Flutter

The basic video_player is working:
https://gist.github.com/andraskende/195e746716e5e4e978356abb09e66a37

Would like to enhance the controls:

- video plays: show controls for first 5 seconds, then hide controls..
- keypress on D-pad controls would appear (play/pause, forward rewind)
- video paused: show controls, if back pressed once hide controls

I tried to add RawKeyboardListener to listen on a keypress on remote but then the controls are not selectable as the RawKeyboardListener takes over..

I guess when the controls are hidden I need RawKeyboardListener to bring up the controls and disable the RawKeyboardListener so the control buttons can be selected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andras

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say it's for Android TV, but then you mentioned a D-Pad, a keyboard and an Escape key. To my knowledge there is no Escape key on Android devices. What is a D-Pad on an Android TV?

Comment: Thanks for the help, will add a youtube video later to explain better.

The primary navigation method on Android TV is through the directional pad (called a D-pad). This pad limits movement to up, down, left, and right directional hardware buttons. The D-pad transfers focus from one object to the nearest object in the direction of the button pressed.

Comment: But that's with a remote, right?

Comment: Yes I need this withe the remote which has the dpad arrow keys... Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how Flutter handles remote input. I'm assuming it takes it as some sort of physical key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar kind of issue where I fixed it with below code:

```
void _onKey(RawKeyEvent e) {
controls();

if (e.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
  switch (e.logicalKey.debugName) {
    case 'Media Play Pause':
    case 'Select':
      setState(() {
        if (_videoViewController.value.isPlaying) {
          _videoViewController.pause();
        } else {
          _videoViewController.play();
        }
      });
      break;
  }
}`
```

Now if you wanted to have a fast forward or back just use the RawKeyboardListener with
specific case to handle it.

You can also use your D-PAD keys to perform such action.

Comment: I tried mentioned code but somehow its not working